# Why is my hair flat?

Tags: hair

I am having an issue getting my hair particle system to show up in object or render mode. Attach below I provided pictures to help with the explination. I have already combed and puffed the hair particles to my liking in particle edit mode however, when I return to object mode or render the image my hair particles dissappear and show as it they are flat against the models head. All except the front hair line particles which are standing straight up? All of the particles are on the same system so I don't understand why part of them are acting one way while the rest act another? I've tried everything the internet has giving me and I'm still as a loss. Please help me figure out why my hair isn't hair. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jngg.jpg)[image]
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out it was the hair dynamic setting. I never did figure out which specific setting in hair dynamics was causing it but when I simply turn off hair dynamics it fixes the issue.